# Will my follower use buff potions like Fortify Conjuration?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

He summons a wolf thing often and I have some spare potions I could give to him, but I'm not sure if it would be any use.

Comment: Step 1. Give him the potions. Step 2. Fight some and wait until he's summoned the wolf thing a couple of times. Step 3. Check his inventory to see if he used any of the potions. Step 4. Report back as I'd like to know as well!

Comment: I can confirm that followers consume store-bought health restoring potions, but not whether they will consume player-made health restoring potions or other potions in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never seen or heard of a follower using any potions. Logically, I understand why they wouldn't, too. Followers are typically used as pack mules, so if you ask them to hold your rare and valuable potion, you don't want them drinking it to combat a pair of bandits.

Comment: They certainly use healing potions. I have no evidence that they'll drink anything else. Give or make him some enchanted armor/robes/jewelry

Comment: I'd believe they would use a healing potion, but I strongly suspect they would never quaff a buff potion. As for gear, that's fine for them to use because you can force them to unequip it to sell. No merchant yet has complained about buying used armor... ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Marcuro (destruction Mage) will go binge drinking on any magicka potions you leave in his supply. Only give him some before a big fight because he will rain lightning on every rabbit he comes across...

Comment: Oh, poor rabbits!

Answer (score 3):

I had the Serana follower equipped with a Vigorous Magika Potion.. and sure enough, she gobbled it up in a fight I had with a Frost Dragon. So yes, I can confirm that followers do eat health/magika potions, but I don't think they touch the buff potions. I'm not sure about Stamina potions.