# What potions can my followers use?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have seen my follower use Healing potions, which is nice, but any other potion I give them, including poisons, remain unused.

Do followers use any potions other than healing potions?

Comment: At least related to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/40245/5902

Comment: Yes, definitely, I see it now. But yes, my question is also broader...

Comment: Jenassa likes invisibility potions. Serana will drink invisibility potions, but only when scared, which doesn't happen often.

Comment: But could this be a copy of the other question stated by @LudoMC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This source claims that followers will drink potions, but not ones that you've made:
http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615803-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/61334541/682887748

This source has evidence that followers use healing potions and they also claim to have seen a potion being consumed animation:
http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Followers#Healing_Potions

Since there is evidence that followers have weapon preferences and combat styles, it stands to reason that they may have a potion preference also. (I cannot confirm this yet.)

A simple test, give your follower some store bought potions and take them to a bandit camp. See what happens.

I've found that if you do any kind of trade, the follower tends to equip their preferred gear. Hard to say how that would affect potion use.

Comment: Hello, did you get the time to test this? What a waste of time it would be to not gain an 'accepted' badge once you put so much effort into writing this answer =)

Comment: @adityamenon 5 days you're waiting and no time to test by yourself? Don't expect us to play the game for you also! ;)

Comment: Well, the choice is Nohl's. Does he want the answer to be accepted? He can test it and tell me. Otherwise, it's okay!

Comment: Sorry. I stopped using followers because they keep making trouble. I also made a pair of boots that let me carry a ton of stuff. So the follower become pointless. I'll try it and see in the next day or so.

Comment: update: I hired stenvar and gave him these potions:
Resist Fire, Resist Cold, Frenzy, Healing, Fortify Health, Fortify one-hand, minor healing, minor stamina, plentiful healing, regeneration. He only drank fortify health. - he's dead.

I'll try a different follower and see what happens to her.

Comment: I've tried a few other followers and it sees like they have favorite potions. You'll need to do trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen my follower use a scroll of magelight with my own eyes. However, I have her loaded with numerous assorted staves/scrolls/potions, and that one instance of her using that scroll in a dark cave is the only consumable animation i can recall seeing her perform .

At one point i gave her a scroll of dead thrall, but as i'm looking through her inventory at this very moment it is gone, so either it bugged, or she used it, the thrall died and I was unaware.

I keep giving her food, Mammoth Cheese Bowls and Mammoth Snouts, but she hasn't used any.