# How do you heal your follower in battle?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

My followers keep getting so close to dying and I only know how to heal myself. I've seen others heal their followers but I can't figure out how to heal mine.

How do you heal your follower in battle?

Answer (score 4):

**Spells**

You need the [Healing Hands](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Healing_Hands) spell. Or [Heal other](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Heal_Other), or [Grand Healing](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Heal_Other). Note that these spells only work on living followers, not undead or robots. If you have dawnguard, [Heal Undead](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Heal_Undead) heals undead.

**Protected Aka "I'm invincible"**

But you should not worry, most non-quest followers are immune to death by normal enemies. They are **[protected](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers#Follower_Death)**, if they get damaged enough to die, they crouch, and enemies stop attacking them. They can only die if hit by a random attack that was actually directed at somebody else, an area of effect spell, or if you the player hit them. They can and will die if poisoned.

**Potions**

You can also give followers healing potions. They will use them to heal themselves. A bit expensive solution perhaps, but it works. Of course, this might be [buggy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50651/what-potions-can-my-followers-use), and they might only use store bought potions. And do not give them fortify health potions. They will die if the combat is still going on when the potion duration runs out.

**Difficulty**

Changing the difficulty might help. Followers might be affected by the difficulty of the game and might take and do full damage. (not 100% sure of this one, but it used to be true for oblivion at least). But if the difficulty does work, then at higher difficulty they would both do more and receive less damage.

**Skyrim helps those who help themselves**

Look at the [list of followers](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers#Permanent_Followers), and select one who has access to restoration magic. These can heal themselves. [Talvas Fathryon](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Talvas_Fathryon) from the dragonborn DLC is one of those followers. Or if you have 500 spare septims, get [Marcurio](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marcurio) in riften. But as followers are a bit suicidal at times, they are not likely to heal themselves when you want them to. Such is life, let them go to [Sovngarde](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Sovngarde) if they are eager to go.

They will not heal you. They hate you that way. You should have let them have that sweetroll.

**Your droids, they are not welcome**

It seems that the [Steadfast Dwarven Sphere](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Steadfast_Dwarven_Sphere) and the [Steadfast Dwarven Spider](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Steadfast_Dwarven_Spider) you can get in dragonborn cannot be healed. I assume they heal outside of battle.

Comment: Difficulty should help, though a bit counterintuitively. Higher difficulties make followers both deal and take less damage, since it affects all NPCs. Similarly, lower-than-normal difficulties probably make them take more, as it will make all NPCs take more. This makes Followers incredibly useful on Master or Legendary.

Comment: I found followers to be pretty useful on master and legendary, but mostly because I could use them as a meat shield and heal them when they went down. Not sure if they did more or less damage. The wiki also isn't clear. But you are probably right.

Comment: Heal Undead is only available siding with Harkon. Necromantic Healing is in Dimhollow Crypt where you meet Serana. Idk if followers take more or less damage based on difficulty. I always equip mine with enchanted legendary gear that armor caps them with really good resistances. They can take a beating on any difficulty. It does seem their damage output changes. Lydia could easy solo a legendary dragon on apprentice, but struggled with Karstag on Expert. A level 50 Vilkas should do over 300 dmg with the battleaxe I gave him, but took 2 hits to kill a 175 health horker on master.

Answer (score -1):

You can also buff your followers (undead and automatons included) with the Illusion school of magic and the Master of the Mind perk.

Call to Arms grants significant combat bonuses to all nearby allies and enemies. If you cast it during the civil war quests before your allies engage the enemy they will easily be able to defeat the opposing side without much assistance from you.

It gives allies 100 in all combat skills, and increased health and stamina for ten minutes.

Comment: I upvoted because it is useful, though not totally accurate. Call to Arms adds +25 to those skills and stats for the time stated, and can actually boost the combat skills over 100 during that time. I do this also right before the big Civil War brawls. If you have the Kindred Mage perk, it adds an additional 10, for a total +35 to all that. After my last battle I checked around and 9 of my original fellow Stormcloaks survived. Forgot to check each one's health and heal them up to full if need be. When the spell wore off, 2 dropped dead on the spot. Whoops. Guess I know better for next time.